# Excel VBA - Splitting Data into New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export the data in two different worksheets ("Price Format" and "Rebates") to a new workbook based on column value (column B in "Price Format" worksheet and column D in "Rebates" worksheet).

[Snapshot of "Price Format" worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWNdB.png)

[Snapshot of "Rebates" worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4xfH.png)

Referring the code from the following video, I was able to correctly export the "Price Format" worksheet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX4xMK2OoEk&t

I tried to set up the code for the second sheet and I'm receiving the following error on the second Advanced Filter:

[image: Run-time error '1004']

Below is the VBA code:

```
Sub Split_Data_in_workbooks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim shD As Worksheet
Dim shT As Worksheet
Dim shR As Worksheet
Dim rngD As Range
Dim rngC As Range
Dim rngE As Range
Dim rngF As Range
Dim rFolder As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbR As Workbook
Dim shO As Worksheet
Dim shQ As Worksheet

Set shD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Price Format")
Set shT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings")
Set shR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rebates")

shD.Range("B:B").Copy shT.Range("A:A")
shR.Range("D:D").Copy shT.Range("B:B")
shT.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
shT.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
rFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\\Output"

Set rngD = shD.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rngC = shT.Range("D1:D2")
Set rngE = shR.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rngF = shT.Range("B1:B2")

shT.Range("D1") = shT.Range("A1")

i = 2

While shT.Cells(i, 1) \<\> ""

shT.Range("D2") = shT.Cells(i, 1)

Set wbR = Workbooks.Add
Set shO = wbR.Worksheets(1)
Set shQ = wbR.Worksheets(2)

rngD.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngC, shO.Range("A1")
**rngE.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngF, shQ.Range("A1")**

shO.Columns.AutoFit
shO.Columns("A:C").Delete
shO.Name = shT.Cells(i, 1)
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

shQ.Columns.AutoFit
shQ.Name = shT.Cells(i, 1)
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

wbR.SaveAs rFolder & shT.Cells(i, 1) & ".xlsx"

i = i + 1

shT.Range("A:B").Clear

Wend

End Sub
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this, appreciate any help!

Comment: A screenshot of the data table and the criteria range would be useful here.

Comment: Hi Tim,

I've added snapshots of the data sheets. The criteria range is just a blank sheet called "Settings".

Comment: The Advanced Filter Criteria range needs to have content....

Answer (score 0):

I think a new sheet(sheets(2)) should be added first.
This error msg often relates to an unexited sheet based on personal experience.

```
Set wbR = Workbooks.Add
Set shO = wbR.Worksheets(1)
Worksheets.Add after:=sho  'add a new sheet
Set shQ = wbR.Worksheets(2)
```